# osm2pgsql error: Cannot detect file format for 'postgres'. Try using -r

Tags: format, passwords, postgis, detect, osm2pgsql

I am trying to import pbf file into postgis database using osm2pgsql.

I can connect to database, but when i try to import the file:

C:\osm2pgsql>osm2pgsql -s -a -d micronesia --flat-nodes C:\osm2pgsql\srbac.osm.pbf -U postgres -W postgres C:\osm2pgsql\micronesia.osm.pbf

at first the program is asking for my password (postgres), and when I retype it, then it sends me an error message:

ERROR: Cannot detect file format for 'postgres'. Try using -r.

Can anyone help me? Why should I define the file format for password?!

I already described the problem

Answer (score 0):

`-W` is the command for a [password prompt](https://osm2pgsql.org/doc/manual.html#command-line-options), so you would have to type it when prompted.

The next argument is the expected pbf file, but here you wrote your password instead so it fails.

Comment: I made it. It works just fine with -w. Thanks a lot!